# merge partial classes in resharper

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, xsd, resharper

Is there any simple possibility to merge partial class definitions to one?
I have one enormous cs file with generated class definitions and a list of their summaries and additional attributes in an extra file. Have no desire to maintain them both.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In ReSharper simply click on the "partial" keyword in any of your partial classes. You should see a hammer icon in the left of the IDE. Click on the hammer icon and select "Merge Partial Declaration". This will merge 2 partial classes to one.

Comment: Thanks! I have overlooked this feature. To mention is that R# merges to the place where the context menu is called without any question.